# What is action ID in Photoshop script?

Tags: photoshop-script

I read a tutorial of photoshop scripting,
and I can't understand this line.

```
//get action ID
cTID = function(s) { return app.charIDToTypeID(s); }; 
sTID = function(s) { return app.stringIDToTypeID(s); };
```

I think these codes are call Photoshop actions, 
but I don't have any references, so 
I can't really understand how to use these.
Why are they need and How to use these?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the code you posted creates convenient aliases for the charIDToTypeID and stringIDToTypeID functions. Those functions simply convert strings to an enumeration value of type PSConstants. For instance,

```
CharIDToTypeID("BD1") //returns 1111765280 which corresponds to PSConstants.phEnumBitDepth1
```

See http://www.pcpix.com/Photoshop/